# Git on localserver cloning through jenkins error

Tags: git, jenkins

everybody,

I have some problem related to the jenkins and git. I created a new user in local server and created a empty git repo. I used jenkins in the other machine to poll the changes in the local server and track changes. I have added the ssh authorized key in the local server for connecting the server directly and in the computer using jenkins, I have a config file to access the identity through the server. But I always get this error, I am not sure what the problem is.

Can anyone help me with this.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@e941c2
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@e941c2
GitAPI created
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
$ /usr/bin/git clone -o origin gituser@192.168.22.112:/home/gituser/Git/multicom/multicom.git "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace"
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone gituser@192.168.22.112:/home/gituser/Git/multicom/multicom.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing /usr/bin/git clone -o origin gituser@192.168.22.112:/home/gituser/Git/multicom/multicom.git /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace
Command returned status code 128: Cloning into /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MultiCom Git/workspace...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:809)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:740)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:784)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:766)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:740)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1195)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:576)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:465)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1404)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the keys are setup for the user jenkins is running under. Try doing a clone from the box, as jenkins users and try. See if plain ssh is happening. Use `-v` ( verbose) output to see what is happening.